# I have a block that I need to show in two regions.

Tags: blocks, theming

How do I show the same block twice? I have a multiple blog site that is created using views. One half is the mens other is the womens. I created specific regions to be shown on only on specific gender--page.tpl files. I just realized I cannot show the same block twice. How will I get this to work. I am also finding that the block may have to be another view as well.

Comment: quick and dirty if the block is a view is to create a second block display identical to the first which will create two blocks that do the same thing.

Comment: Yea I am creating a view and will clone it when it is ready. I actually already cloned it but have a feeling that I will need to update the clone. How do I do this or can I delete the old clone and re-clone when ready.

Comment: each clone is a view to itself so you can do whatever you want with it

Comment: It doesn't even need to be a clone. Just add another block display to the current view and change its filter.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [MultiBlock](http://drupal.org/project/multiblock). Another would be to use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) which would also have value if you wanted to have different layouts for the gender specific pages.